# IronPython Parse XML wrong encoding

Tags: .net, xml, encoding, ironpython

I'm reading an XML file using the XmlDocument class, but whenever it reads the value of an attribute it converts the danish characters like 'æ' 'ø' and 'å' to \xf8 for example, which later makes the matching of a regular expression fail.

I've tried doing like this:

```
XMLDoc = XmlDocument()
XMLDoc.Load(StreamReader(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
```

but when i do:

```
tablename = N.GetAttribute("TableName")
```

it still comes out as:

u'Reg_konto_bel\xf8b'

where i would like it to be simply: Reg_konto_beløb
The Xml file is encoded in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)
and i've also declared that at the top of the .py file

```
# encoding: ISO-8859-1
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The encoding you specify on top of your python file ([PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)) should have no influence on what happens in .NET's XML libraries. The encoding of the XML file should be specified in the file itself or explicitly when reading like in your example.

Even though your XML file is most likely stored in the correct encoding and read using the correct encoding the in memory representation of [strings in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) is done using Unicode.
The lowercase *u*-prefix states that the following string is a Unicode string.

Using Unicode is the default for many technologies nowadays and you should evaluate if expressing your regular expressions and other processing steps using Unicode would be the most flexible and fault tolerant solution.